# Is this bark beetle going to be a problem?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

This little (around 3mm in length) beetle is one of many that infested a gingerbread heart in our house. It seems to be some kind of bark beetle. My question is what exact species it is likely to be and whether it is a danger to our wooden floor, furniture, maybe even roof. We live in Germany.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stegobium paniceum.](https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/stored/drugstore_beetle.htm) (Biscuit beetle, bread beetle, drugstore beetle).

[image: Adult form, dark with large head.]

<sup>Copyright [Siga](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Siga), via Wikipedia, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) 2022.</sup>

[image: Grub of beetle.]

<sup>Copyright marked, via entnemdept.ufl.edu, fair usage, 2022.</sup>

Characteristics:

- Adult can be up to 3.5 mm in length.
- Worldwide distribution though it is more common in warmer climates.
- Notched antennae (like the teeth of a saw).
- Diet consisting of a diverse range of dried foods and spices, as well as hair, leather, books, birdseed, dried pet-food, and museum specimens. The drugstore beetle is also known as the biscuit or bread beetle since it can live on biscuit or bread crumbs.
- Larval form is a small, white grub. Period in this phase can be several months. Larvae do most of the damage this creature causes (great economic harm).
- Likely to eat through foil-sealed food packaging.
- Lives in obligatory symbiosis with a yeast fungus.

Pest control measures:

- Thorough cleaning.
- Destroy infested material.
- Freezing below -20 Celsius (-4 Fahrenheit).
- Diatomaceous earth sprinkled in corners may help.

Resembles, but not to be confused with a related species:
[Anobium punctatum.](http://demo.olivelogo.com/propertymaintainltd/woodworm/) (Common furniture beetle, woodworm).

Comment: This seems almost certainly correct. Not sure this is great news, but at least it's not going to bring down the house.

Comment: I taught Latin grades 3 -12. That was the *magistra* in me bursting out, sorry. :-/

Comment: Not at all. It's just that no-one taught us about *pre*-classical Latin. Never even thought to look anything from that period up before. I'm all too glad to learn. @anongoodnurse

Comment: I really like the etymology of words (English, Latin, French, Norse, whichever.) It never occurred to me to stop at some arbitrary line.

Comment: For me, it's not so much that I stopped at a line, just that I've been given snapshots of languages at school, and I've continued taking them, increasing the range of languages as I go. Hadn't gotten around to looking at what came *before* Catullus, Cisero etc., except when looking at Ancient Greek words that get kicked-up in English from time to time. My paternal aunt is the real linguist of the family with her Russian, Spanish, Italian, Bulgarian and a heavy dose of comparative linguistics. Weird to think that she never used it in any of her jobs. @anongoodnurse

Comment: Wow!!! Kudos to her, seriously! French was my first language, so the Romance languages are easy (Well, not Portuguese) and Latin, of course, informs those. Kudos to you, too, for following Greek. Once the letters change shape, I wimp out. :( Only used French twice in my decades as a doc. Spanish? Nearly every day.